# How to keep an internal framework and applications independently versioned?

Tags: git, svn, frameworks, project-management, versioning

Our company uses an internal PHP MVC framework for most of our projects, which does a lot of heavy lifting and simplifies our development pipeline.

However, we're trying to implement a concise version control, that would centralize the framework code and avoid multiple copies, repeating bugs that have already been fixed, etc.

Our requirements would be:

- Centralized code storage, where every developer can tap into the latest version of any app/framework.
- App developers should be able to update the framework in their app to the latest version
- App developers should also be able to submit patches to the framework code, independent of their app versions
- Limited access to framework code. Something like the requests in GitHub to let developers submit framework code patches would be great.

We tried SVN, but it is very error prone to make the root dir a repository and have a parent dir with another. We also tried Git, but apparently it does not support nested repositories.

Any clues on how we could deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at submodules. More on them in progit.org/book.